# How to approximate the data curve with a function?

Tags: interpolation, modeling

I want to approximate a data curve (the purple curve [in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2rQS.png)) with one function, so I can use it in my engineering simulation.

### Some explanation of purple curve

- The curly part is a sinusoid;
- The flat part of the purple curve is a constant.

The aforementioned information suggests that the purple curve can be described as a *piecewise function*. But in some situation, the *piecewise function* does not suit for other engineering software. I'd like to know how to use **Mathematica** to change the *piecewise function* into an elementary function, without dependence on the particular **Mathematica functions**.

It would also help if you could briefly explain the mathematical technique to approximate this purple curve with one function.

Thanks!

[image]

### Revision for my requirement

*2017-8-16 15:44*

When I talk about `one function`, I mean it is a combination of `basic` math functions, such as `sin(x)`,`cos(x)`,`tan(x)`,`arcsin(x)`,`1+x^2+ln(x+3)`. These functions should be supported commonly by most of the CAD, CAE softwares.

On the other hand, some complicate functions supplied by Mathematica, such as `LowpassFilter[]`,`InterpolatingFunction[]`, may not be supported by other softwares. Consequently, it should not appear in the resultant function.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the process that generated this curve, or at least the context in which it arises?

Comment: It's hard to say anything relevant without info on where all this came from.

Comment: This is the motion of a flapping wing of bird. And this curve is obtained by watching the slow-motion video of the bird when it flaps wings. To some degree, this curve can be viewed as drawing by hand. 囧rz

Comment: Okay, so you have the data points that generated the curve?

Comment: @J.M. Not yet. This picture is a screenshot from other researcher's paper. I want to carry out a research based on it. Currently, it may be not proper to ask for experiment data since I haven't formulate my research problem.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a *Mathematica* question anymore. Since you know where it came from, isn't there a theory describing the motion?

Comment: @J.M. the most essential problem of my question does not relate closely to **Mathematica**. I once considered knowledge of `System Moleling` in **Mathematica** to approximate the time-series experiment data. But after a survey of the manual I found `Fitting and Interpolation` section is not my cup of tea. In the end, I prefer to post my problem and want to see   how **Mathematica** can be used as an analying tool to decompose the practical problem in real life. At this point, the post do make sense for **Mathematica**.

Comment: If you have data points, you can fit something to them. But coming up with a(n elementary) function that models your data is not a *Mathematica* problem at all, you either hit the books or think something up, and only then do you write something in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M. You remind me of revising my question. My post may looks like a more formal *Mathematica Question*. I will make it. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just do a Fourier transform of your data?  Check out the documentation for `Fourier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are *exactly* looking for, here are a few possibilities.

Starting from a sine wave, I chopped negative values (blue curve). Then I changed the sign of every second "bell" shape:

```
Plot[{Max[0, Sin[x]], Max[0, Sin[x]]*Sign[Sin[x/2 - Pi/2]]}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

**Low-pass filtering approach**

Then, since the yellow curve is not very smooth, I sampled it and used a `LowpassFilter`:

```
tab = Table[Max[0, Sin[x]]*Sign[Sin[x/2 - Pi/2]], {x, 0, 20, 0.02}];
ListPlot[LowpassFilter[tab, 0.03]]
```

[image]

You can play on the smoothness of the curve by changing the parameter in `LowpassFilter`. Now, if you actually want a function, you can use `InterpolatingFunction` for instance.

**Smoothening the crossing of the $x$-axis by $\sin$**

Based on your edit, this is another approach. The idea is to smoothen the crossings of the $x$-axis by the function. This can be done by replacing $Sin$ by $Sin^3$:

```
Plot[Max[0, Sin[x]^3]*Sign[Sin[x/2 - Pi/2]], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

**Image-based approach**

You can also extract the purple curve with the following (unefficient) approach:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2rQS.png"];
data = ImageData@img;
convert[pix_] := 
  If[Norm[pix - {142, 83, 161}/255] < 0.2, pix, {1, 1, 1}];
data2 = Map[convert, data, {2}];
Image[data2]
```

[image]

From `data2` you could extract the points corresponding to the purple points with

```
pos = Table[
   Position[data2[[All, i]], _?(Norm[#] < .99 &)][[All, 1]], {i, Dimensions[data2][[2]]}];
pos2 = Select[pos, Length@# > 0 &][[All, 1]]
ListPlot[pos2, DataRange -> 2]
```

[image]

This does not yield an analytic function but can be used to compare with your attempts.

Comment: thanks. your solution is novel, however I wish the resultant function does not contain the *advanced* functions, such `LowpassFilter[]`, since they may be not supported by other engineering software. Still, Your thinking is amazing! it offers a method to solve similar problem.

Comment: I rethink your solution, and I suppose `Max[0, Sin[x]]*Sign[Sin[x/2 - Pi/2]]` almost reaches my expected result except for the `LowpassFiler[]`. I wonder if there is other way to smooth the transition of the purlple curve? It is best to use the **basic** math function.

Comment: Amazing! wonderful work, and useful utility.